# Basic for loop script

Tags: linux, for-loop

I am trying to create a basic for loop script that outputs a shopping list into an appended file. Here is my script so far but its not capturing all of my items when I cat.

```
echo "enter items seperated by a space"
read items

for variable in $items
do
 echo "$variable" > Shopping_List  
done

cat Shopping_List
```

Comment: You're not appending.  You need `echo "$variable" >> Shopping_List`.  (Note `>>` verses `>`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `>>` to append. `>` is for overwriting.

```
echo "$variable" >> Shopping_List
```

Comment: That wouldn't put each word on a separate line.  Looks like that's what OP wants.

Comment: @codeforester It does for me. Doesn't `echo` output a new line by default?

Comment: It does, but not after every word.

Comment: @codeforester `echo` automatically outputs the trailing newline as well. The man page says you have to use the `-n` switch to disable it.

Comment: @codeforester: _variable_ is the control variable inside a loop, and contains single words.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your loop with `>` this way, which is a tad more efficient:

```
for variable in $items
do
  echo "$variable"
done > Shopping_List
```

You can also use `printf` and do away with the loop:

```
printf "%s\n" $items > Shopping_List
```

In both these cases, the `items` is not enclosed in double quotes, shell does the word splitting based on the default `IFS` which is space, tab, and newline.

Comment: `printf %s A B C` results in `ABC`

Comment: Try `printf "%s\n" A B C` - that's why my script is doing.

Comment: Right. I don't understand the rationale, but you are true. Or perhaps yes, I am getting it slowly...